# C++ returning default value, NullObjectPattern

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, coding-style

I have a question regarding some kind of Null Object Pattern.
When I think of a getter (I know that we should avoid that but suppose)
I see 2 ways of doing that.

Suppose that we have a class `NullObject.cpp`

1)

```
class NullObject
{
    std::vector<SomeObject> get() { return {}; }
}

class SomeImplementation
{
     std::vector<SomeObject> get() { return someVectorMember; }
{

const std::vector<SomeObject>& object = instance.get();
```

So in first example we will always returning by value and assign to `const Object&`

2)

```
class NullObject
{
    const std::vector<SomeObject>& get() { return member; }

    static std::vector<SomeObject> member;
}

class SomeImplementation
{
     const std::vector<SomeObject>& get() { return someVectorMember; }
{

const std::vector<SomeObject>& object = instance.get();
```

In this case we have static member in Null class so we can return a const reference.

Question: Which is better in case of performance for example? 
          Which is better in case of "clean" code?
          Is there any (better) option? 
          Maybe my examples are wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "Better" has various meanings.  The solution that would be "better" for you depends on how you use the returned object, how often these are called, do two `NullObject`s need to compare equal, etc.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing the exact context. However, you usually just return by value unless there's a convincing reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: It depends on the context of your application, but there are some serious safety concerns you should consider when using the second technique.

---

Better is subjective in this case, as it depends on the context, but there are some objective trade-offs and safety concerns that distinguish between the two techniques.

In the first case, you create completely distinct objects for each call. This requires that some cycles are used to instantiate the object. Depending on the complexity of the object, this could be trivial or it could be very expensive. For example, if the constructor of the object makes a call over a network and blocks, continuously constructing these objects can be a poor performance decision. Whether these are serious performance issues depends on the context in which it is used. For example:

- How many times is this method called, on average, over the life of the system?
- How long does the returned object stay in scope, and thus, occupy stack space?
- How valuable is stack space in this particular application? This approach is arguably simpler since it does not require a field (whether class or static) to be added to the class.

The second approach saves the overhead of construction upon each call (it is performed once when static variables are initialized), but it has some serious safety concerns that should be considered. The object returned is shared by all clients that call this method, which can be an issue if some entity changes the values of the shared object. Although the shared object is returned as a `const` reference, this does not mean that the value of the object cannot change (i.e. the internal fields of the `SomeObject` object can change). There are three direct ways to change the value, even though it is returned as a `const` (there are even more if more intrusive means are used):

1. The `NullObject` changes the value. This shared object is not `const` with respect to `NullObject`, and therefore, `NullObject` can change the value `SomeObject` if `SomeObject` is mutable. If a change is made, this change will be seen by all clients that obtained a reference to this shared object. If the object is truly immutable (see (2) and (3) for ways around immutability), then there is nothing to worry about, since the value of the shared object cannot be changed once it is instantiated, but if the object is mutable, its value can be changed and that change would be seen by all clients that obtained the shared object.
2. Fields declared `mutable` change even though the object is `const`. The clients that use the object do not know about its internals (i.e. encapsulation), so they may be unaware that there are internal fields in `SomeObject` that are marked `mutable` and may change, even though the returned object is `const`. For example:

   ```
   class SomeObject {

       public: void doSomething() const {
           // Do some logic
           this->count++;
       }

       public: const int& getCounter() const {
           return this->counter;
       }

       private: mutable int counter = 0;
   }
   ```

   This may be bad form, it is possible, and therefore, must be considered.
3. The constness of the return value is cast away. For example:

   ```
   std::vector<SomeObject>& mutable_vector = const_cast<std::vector<SomeObject>&>(instance.get());
   ```

Taking these three issues into account, it is important to be very precise about what type of objects are shared in C++, even if they are denoted as `const`. Even though the `const` keyword may appear to provide immutability, there are ways around such immutability, and some of these ways can be performed by the client.

In general, the performance of each solution will depend on the context of your application and you should do performance testing using both techniques in order to understand the impact to your application in terms of computation (how long does it take to execute), memory consumption (how much room does it take up when executing), and a host of other factors that pertain to your context. This problem also amounts to a more general problem: When to cache values. In this particular case, the value is intended to be immutable, so you do not have to worry about Time to Live (TTL), expiration of meaning, or stale data, but some of the concepts do translate, such as "is it worth it to introduce the complexity of caching for the benefit of performance?"